# How to solve NFS cross-mounting ordering "dead-lock"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs4

I have 3 NFS servers, all basically doing cross mounts, e.g.:

- Server "A" mounts from "B"/"C"
- Server "B" mounts from "A"/"C"
- Server "C" mounts from "A"/"B"

Obviously this creates a rather annoying challenge when bringing up the entire network (e.g. for example, if I have a complete network shutdown for UPS treatment) and I now need to bring up all 3 servers, I will get various NFS mount issues and timeouts preventing me from just restarting all 3 servers.

Is there a standard Linux / Or more specifically in ubuntu (I'm using 16.04 right now) to make NFS cross mounts like these actually work without having to manually log in to all 3 machines (in my case) and run a series of restart commands...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to solve your problem and it is called *autofs* aka *automount*. What *autofs* does is to mount the shares only when the mountpoint is accessed on the client and not automatically on boot.
But if you e.g. have services running on *server A* that rely on data that is stored on a *server B* share, then *autofs* will not help you because as soon as the service on *server A* starts, *autofs* would try to mount the share from *server B*.

There is a good overview with configuration examples [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs). You can also provide the *autofs maps* over LDAP or NIS to overcome the local configuration.